# яндекс карты доступ к элементу кластера через балун

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Добрый день!
Существует трудность, добавляю Placemarks на карту, на каждый Placemark навешано событие click, через кластеризатор, точки с одинаковыми координатами кластеризуются, создан макет балуна, в балун выводиться id метки, по клику на строчку в балуне хочу инициировать событие навешанное на Placemark состоящее в кластере. Не могу получить ссылку на точку в кластере.

```
BalloonContentLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
        '<ul class=list>' + 
        '{% for geoObject in properties.geoObjects %}' + 
        '<li id="{{geoObject.properties.lac}}{{geoObject.properties.cid}}"></li>' +
        '{% endfor %}' + 
        '</ul>', {

        build : function() {
        BalloonContentLayout.superclass.build.call(this);
        geoObjects = this.getData().properties.get('geoObjects');
        geoObjects2 = this.getData().properties;
        var fielsObjects = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < geoObjects.length; i++) {
            var element = document.getElementById(geoObjects[i].properties._data.lac+geoObjects[i].properties._data.cid);
            element.innerHTML = geoObjects[i].properties._data.hintContent;
            element.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                console.log(geoObjects2);
                geoObjects[0].events.fire('click');
                });


        }


    },

        clear : function() {
             this.getElement().innerHTML = '';
            BalloonContentLayout.superclass.clear.call(this);
        }
    });
    clusterer = new ymaps.Clusterer({

        groupByCoordinates : false,
        margin : 0,

        clusterIcons : [{
            href : 'image/1.gif',
            size : [40, 40],
            offset : [-20, -20]
        }, {
            href : 'image/1.gif',
            size : [60, 60],
            offset : [-30, -30]
        }],
        clusterDisableClickZoom : true,
        clusterOpenBalloonOnClick : true,
        clusterBalloonPanelMaxMapArea : 0,
        clusterBalloonContentLayout : BalloonContentLayout,
        hideIconOnBalloonOpen: false
    });

    getPointData = function(iCoord) {
        return {
            id : iCoord.operator,
            az : iCoord.azimut,
            sector : iCoord.corner,
            length : iCoord.length,
            lat : iCoord['latitude'],
            lon : iCoord['longitude'],
            child : false,
            lac : iCoord.lac,
            cid : iCoord.cid,
            hintContent : "lac: " + iCoord.lac + " cid: " + iCoord.cid,
            //          clusterCaption: 'метка <strong>' + iCoord.cid + '</strong>'
        };
    };

    getPointOptions = function() {
        return {
            iconLayout : 'default#image',
            iconImageHref : 'image/1.gif',
            iconImageSize : [20, 40]
        };
    };

    getSector = function(e) {
        if (!e.get('target').properties.get('child')) {
            var sector = getAreaCoord([e.get('target').properties.get('lat'), e.get('target').properties.get('lon')], e.get('target').properties.get('az'), e.get('target').properties.get('sector'), e.get('target').properties.get('length'));
            var triangle = new ymaps.Polygon([[[e.get('target').properties.get('lat'), e.get('target').properties.get('lon')], sector.point2, sector.point3]], {
                id : e.get('target').properties.get('lac') + e.get('target').properties.get('cid'),
                hintContent : "az: " + e.get('target').properties.get('az') + " sec: " + e.get('target').properties.get('sector') + " len: " + e.get('target').properties.get('length')
            }, {  });
            console.log(triangle + "  triangle  ");
            console.log(e.get('target') + "  placemark  ");
            triangle.setParent(e.get('target'));
            e.get('target').properties.set('child', true);
            (e.get('target').getParent()).getParent().add(triangle);
        } else {
            (e.get('target').getParent()).getParent().each(function(item, i) {
                if (item.properties != undefined) {
                    if (item.properties._data.id === (e.get('target').properties.get('lac') + e.get('target').properties.get('cid'))) {
                        item.getParent().remove(item);
                        e.get('target').properties.set('child', false);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };

    getSectorClaster = function () {
        console.log(this.id);
        var cluster = objectManager.clusters.balloon.getData();
        console.log(cluster);
    };

    geoObjects = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < coord.length; i++) {
        geoObjects[i] = new ymaps.Placemark([coord[i]['latitude'], coord[i]['longitude']], getPointData(coord[i]), getPointOptions());
        geoObjects[i].events.add('click', function(e) {
            getSector(e)

        });
    }

    clusterer.add(geoObjects);
    this.add(clusterer);
    myMap.geoObjects.add(this);

    clusterer.events.add('balloonopen', function(e) {
        console.log(e.get('cluster').properties);
        console.log(e.get('Placemark').properties);
//      baloonContentData = e.get('cluster').properties;
```

Comment: Я не совсем понял сути проблемы. Вы же обращаетесь к списку геообъектов. Сделайте замыкание при навешивании события onclick=getSectorClaster

Comment: у меня в балуне кластера выводятся данные по меткам, по клику на балун (названию метки), хочу получить ссылку на саму метку.
В принципе проблему эту решил уже, в build нахожу эту метку в geoObjects, далее ее отправляю в getSector, но при получении данных о родителе метки получаю null или ошибку, хотя в консоле вижу что у элемента есть родитель.

Comment: точнее я не метку отправляю в getSector, а инициирую программно клик по метке через fire geoObjects[0].events.fire('click');

Comment: немного изменил код

Answer (score 1):

Проблему бы вроде решил, написав кривой код.
Подбираю из базы точки, наношу на карту, у которых точки совпадают собираю в кластер, после кликаю по кластеру открывается балун, там выведены данные через слой балуна о точках, после кликаю по точке в балуне -> нахожу ссылку на Placemark через geoObjects и имитирую клик навешанный ранее, и отрисовываю область покрытия.
Вот как то так.

```
function visibleStation2() {
var coord = JSON.parse(ajax('stationData', '*', 'zapros', 'operator', 'where', '=', this.operator_id));

BalloonContentLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
    '<ul class=list>' + 
    '{% for geoObject in properties.geoObjects %}' + 
    '<li id="{{geoObject.properties.lac}}{{geoObject.properties.cid}}"></li>' +
    '{% endfor %}' + 
    '</ul>', {

    build : function() {
        BalloonContentLayout.superclass.build.call(this);
        geoObjects = this.getData().properties.get('geoObjects');
        for (var i = 0; i < geoObjects.length; i++) {
            var element = document.getElementById(geoObjects[i].properties._data.lac+geoObjects[i].properties._data.cid);
            console.log(element);
            element.innerHTML = geoObjects[i].properties._data.hintContent;
            element.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                geoObjects.forEach(function(item,i){
                    if(e.target.id === (item.properties._data.lac+item.properties._data.cid)) {
                        item.setParent(clusterer);
                        item.events.fire('click');
                        if(item.options._options.iconImageHref == '') {
                            item.options._options.iconImageHref = 'image/1.gif';
                        } else {
                            item.options._options.iconImageHref = '';
                        }
                    }
                });

                });
        }

    },

    clear : function() {
         this.getElement().innerHTML = '';
        BalloonContentLayout.superclass.clear.call(this);
    }
});

clusterer = new ymaps.Clusterer({

    groupByCoordinates : true,
    margin : 0,

    clusterIcons : [{
        href : 'image/1.gif',
        size : [40, 40],
        offset : [-20, -20]
    }, {
        href : 'image/1.gif',
        size : [60, 60],
        offset : [-30, -30]
    }],
    clusterDisableClickZoom : true,
    clusterOpenBalloonOnClick : true,
    clusterBalloonPanelMaxMapArea : 0,
    clusterBalloonContentLayout : BalloonContentLayout,
    hideIconOnBalloonOpen: false,

});

getPointData = function(iCoord) {
    return {
        id : iCoord.operator,
        az : iCoord.azimut,
        sector : iCoord.corner,
        length : iCoord.length,
        lat : iCoord['latitude'],
        lon : iCoord['longitude'],
        child : false,
        lac : iCoord.lac,
        cid : iCoord.cid,
        hintContent : "lac: " + iCoord.lac + " cid: " + iCoord.cid,
        //          clusterCaption: 'метка <strong>' + iCoord.cid + '</strong>'
    };
};

getPointOptions = function() {
    return {
        iconLayout : 'default#image',
        iconImageHref : 'image/1.gif',
        iconImageSize : [20, 40]
    };

};

getSector = function(e) {
    if (!e.get('target').properties.get('child')) {
        var sector = getAreaCoord([e.get('target').properties.get('lat'), e.get('target').properties.get('lon')], e.get('target').properties.get('az'), e.get('target').properties.get('sector'), e.get('target').properties.get('length'));
sector.unshift([e.get('target').properties.get('lat'), e.get('target').properties.get('lon')]);
var triangle = new ymaps.Polygon([sector], {
            id : e.get('target').properties.get('lac') + e.get('target').properties.get('cid'),
            hintContent : "az: " + e.get('target').properties.get('az') + " sec: " + e.get('target').properties.get('sector') + " len: " + e.get('target').properties.get('length')
        }, {  });

        triangle.setParent(e.get('target'));
        e.get('target').properties.set('child', true);
        (e.get('target').getParent()).getParent().add(triangle);
    } else {
        (e.get('target').getParent()).getParent().each(function(item, i) {
            if (item.properties != undefined) {
                if (item.properties._data.id === (e.get('target').properties.get('lac') + e.get('target').properties.get('cid'))) {
                    item.getParent().remove(item);
                    e.get('target').properties.set('child', false);
                }
            }
        });
    }
};

geoObjects = [];

for (var i = 0; i < coord.length; i++) {
    geoObjects[i] = new ymaps.Placemark([coord[i]['latitude'], coord[i]['longitude']], getPointData(coord[i]), getPointOptions());
    geoObjects[i].events.add('click', function(e) { getSector(e)});
}



clusterer.add(geoObjects);
this.add(clusterer);
myMap.geoObjects.add(this);

}
```